# What order are cache layers when using spring @Caching?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

Using the [@Caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-caching) annotation, spring allows adding multiple [@Cacheable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable) annotations to a single method. Since [conditional caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition) is possible using @Cacheable, in what order are the annotations and therefore the conditions evaluated - are values stored in multiple caches if more than one evaluates to true? Again during cache get are all conditions evaluated in parallel and value fetched from any cache whose condition evaluates to true?

for example consider :

```
@Caching( cacheable = { @Cacheable(cacheNames="smallBooks", condition="#name.length < 32"), @Cacheable(cacheNames="fiction", condition="#domain.equals('fiction')"), @Cacheable(cacheNames="everythingelse")})
public Book findBook(String name, String domain)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no parallel evaluation, the `@Cacheable` annotations are getting [gathered in the order of definition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/c036e4019f2ebfbe6a94cc6b8bb0acff98c7dfa5/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/annotation/SpringCacheAnnotationParser.java#L164-L172) as per the linked code (cacheable property is an array afterall). It's important to realise that you are defining 3 separate caches under different names and conditions.

Since I don't know your use case here is a slight alteration of the [Spring Caching Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) :

```
//..
@Override
@Caching( cacheable = {
        @Cacheable(cacheNames = "sth"),
        @Cacheable(cacheNames="everythingelse")
})
public Book getByIsbn(String isbn) {
    simulateSlowService();
    return new Book(isbn, "Some book");
}
//..
```

and by defining the `DEBUG` level at the caching package in the Spring Boot's `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.cache=DEBUG
```

You can see how it's actually getting loaded as separate caches:

```
2016-11-29 00:52:26.472 DEBUG 23426 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.AnnotationCacheOperationSource   : Adding cacheable method 'getByIsbn' with attribute: [Builder[public hello.Book hello.SimpleBookRepository.getByIsbn(java.lang.String)] caches=[sth] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false', Builder[public hello.Book hello.SimpleBookRepository.getByIsbn(java.lang.String)] caches=[everythingelse] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false']
```